# D3.js: append path to a rect

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I'm drawing a chart in D3.js, and I'm using a `<rect>` as the actual charting area (lines, plots, etc.). The plan is to only append the path to the `<rect>` such that it doesn't overflow the charting zone when user drags around. Right now it looks like this:

[image: Path overflow when user drags around]

But when I tried to do:

```
var path = rect.append('path').attr(...)
```

The path itself doesn't even show up. The original version is just to append path to svg, whic works:

```
var path = svg.append('path').attr(...)
```

I also cannot do `overflow:hidden` like regular HTML elements because `path` is not contained inside the `rect`.

If appending `path` to `rect` is not possible or recommended, what is the best way to limit the "activity area" of path so that it doesn't cause overflow?

Comment: How are you defining `rect`? Also I'm not sure if a `rect` element semantically is supposed to have `path` elements in it. Is there a specific reason you need to use `rect`? If its just for styling, perhaps it makes more sense to use CSS to style something.

Comment: You can't append a `path` element to a `rect` as far as I know. If you want to group elements together, then you should use a `g` (grouping) element. This is convenient if you want to have several elements with the same `transform` attribute and the like.

Comment: @JSBob Is there anyway to have a `g` element fixed? Such that when I drag on the chart, only the `path` gets moved? I tried using css `position: absolute` but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Look into `clipPath`. It lets you define a shape (a rect, in your case) that masks another shape (the path, in your case), cropping away anything that falls outside of it. There is no `overflow:hidden` in SVG nor `position:absolute`.

Comment: @benjaminz If you want only the path to move, you could create custom [drag](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Drag-Behavior) behaviour. There are a few options with this, one being making drag only move the `path`, and the other having it move everything and then reset the transform of the `rect`.

Comment: @meetamit the clippath solution works for me, thank you! If you could write as an answer it would be great.

Comment: @benjaminz glad to help! To be a good answer I'd have to write some code showing how to implement, which would be quite time consuming (and difficult without having a jsFiddle showing what you have so far). But if you're good to go then it's all good.

Comment: @meetamit - had exactly the same thinking as me. Hope you don't mind though, I decided to post an actual answer.

Comment: @ian - Of course I don't mind. It's good for the syndicate :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that you can't see the `path` inside the `rect` is because SVG `rect` elements don't support having child elements, they aren't containers.

What you need to do is include an `g` (group) element which is a container and instead place both your `rect` and your `path` inside it. This is how a large number of `D3` examples work because it means you can interact with the group, instead of all the individual sub-elements, which is great if you're zooming/moving things around.

In your case if you don't want you're line to be visible outside of the `rect` then you can simply omit drawing those points in the first place, or clip them once you have drawn them using a clip path.

I've put together a small example to illustrate using a clip-path with a rectangle which matches your use case. The blue stroke illustrates the area that would be filled without a clip-path. Once the clip-path has been applied however, you can see the actual filled area is much smaller than the full definition of the rectangle.

```css
.fill {
  fill: steelblue;
}

.outline {
  stroke: steelblue;
  fill: none;
}
```

```html
<svg width="300" height="300">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="demoClip">
      <rect x="30" y="0" height="100" width="100"/>
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  
  <rect class="fill" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" clip-path="url(#demoClip)"/>
  <rect class="outline" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200"/>
</svg>
```